# Get UserId of shared calendar's owner using MS Graph API

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I want to [get the User's profile](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) that shared a Calendar with me but this call needs the `id` or `userPrincipalName`:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

The shared calendar only returns:

```
{
    "id": "**********************************************=",
    "name": "Lala Lalala",
    "color": "auto",
    "changeKey": "Epg+nQ9k3kuTN16cfoLtwAAAsZgDvA==",
    "canShare": false,
    "canViewPrivateItems": false,
    "canEdit": true,
    "owner": {
        "name": "Lala Lalala",
        "address": "Lalala@outlook.com"
    }
}
```

So how can I get the `id` or `userPrincipalName` of the shared calendar's owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Work/School Accounts (Azure AD tenants), the `userPrincipalName` is the owner's address (i.e. `alias@aad.domain.com`):

```
"owner": {
    "name": "Lala Lalala",
    "address": "Lalala@outlook.com"
}
```

Assuming they're in the same tenant as your, you can retrieve their profile using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{owner.address}`.

**Important**: This does not, however, apply to Personal Accounts (MSA/Outlook.com). I only mention this because your example used `Lalala@outlook.com` as the `address`.

Since Outlook.com is effectively a "single user" tenant, the *only* user you can retrieve is yourself (`/me`). Just as you cannot access a user's data from another company's AAD, you cannot retrieve another Outlook.com user's profile. If you consider the pricacey implications of my access your personal contact information, it makes sense why this rule is in place.

Answer (score 0):

No directly  way to implement what you want. But you can get the id or userPrincipalName by two steps:

1. Get calendars whose owner is not you, the response like you have posted([official docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars)):

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
2. Use the **address** in the **owner** to call the following API:

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{address}

The response with **id** and **userPrincipalName**:

> ```
> {
>     "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
>     "id": "5eec0ff7-b007-48c4-87ae-7cddb085f234",
>     "businessPhones": [],
>     "displayName": "...",
>     "givenName": "...",
>     "jobTitle": null,
>     "mail": "test@test.com",
>     "mobilePhone": "8612345678",
>     "officeLocation": "No WorkSpace",
>     "preferredLanguage": null,
>     "surname": "s",
>     "userPrincipalName": "test@test.com"
> }
> ```